# Django templates built-in filters: Using a variable value in an argument

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Using Django's built-in [yesno](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/builtins/#yesno) filter, I need to insert one of these values:

1. The word "I"
2. The value of the variable `owner_name`

Here's the code I've tried to use in my template:

```
"Look what {{ is_owner|yesno:"I,{{ owner_name }}" }} created!"
```

Using the code above causes the following error:

> Could not parse the remainder: ':"I,{{ owner_name' from
>   'is_owner|yesno:"I,{{ owner_name'

So how do I escape a variable inside a filter's argument?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Another thing you can do is concatenate the arguments using the `with` template tag and `add` filter:

```
{% with yesno_args="I,"|add:owner_name %}
"Look what {{ is_owner|yesno:yesno_args }} created!"
{% endwith %}
```

I think this is simpler than having to add a custom filter.

Comment: Note that the `|add:` filter only works if the variable is also a string. This won't work: `{% with val="Hi"|add:non_string_type %}` but this will: `{% with val="Hi"|add:string_type %}`

Answer (score 2):

You can create a [custom filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters) to do what you want.

It would look something like `{{ is_owner|my_yesno:owner_name }}`

With the custom filter

```
from django.template.defaultfilters import yesno

def my_yesno(value, arg):
   yes_no_list = ['I', arg]
   return yesno(value, yes_no_list)
```

This would let you reuse yesno while creating the list in your wrapper `my_yesno`.  You can alternatively just write your own logic if you want to do something differently as well.  Be sure to `{% load %}` your custom filter as well.